# How to get each value inside <li> with <span> tag BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML document which looks like below, *self.soup* is BeautifulSoup object. I tried to scrape data inside list element. List element looks like below:

```
 <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
           <span class="strong">Name</span>
           <span class="pull-right">Piter</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
           <span class="strong">Year</span>
           <span class="pull-right">2017</span>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

python file **scrape.py**

```
  #person is a array
  need = { 'Name' : 'name',
           'Year' : 'year'
  }
```

*First tried*

```
  specs = self.soup.select("ul.list-group li.list-group-item") 
  if  len(specs) > 0 :
        for data in specs :
            text = data.get_text()
            if need.has_key( data[0].strip()) : 
                 if need[ data[0].strip() ] not in person or person[ need[ data[0].strip() ] ] == '':
                    person[ need[ text[0].strip() ] ] = text[1].strip()
```

First Error

```
 File "scraper.py", line 68, in scrape
    if need.has_key( data[0].strip()) : 
 File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bs4/element.py", line 1011, in__getitem__
 KeyError: 0
```

*Second tried*

```
  specs = self.soup.select("ul.list-group li.list-group-item")
  if  len(specs) > 0 :
        for data in specs :
            text = data.get_text()
            if need.has_key( data[0].strip()) : 
                 if need[ data[0].strip() ] not in person or person[ need[ data[0].strip() ] ] == '':
                    person[ need[ text[0].strip() ] ] = text[1].strip()
```

Second Error

```
  File "site_scrapers/v12software.scraper.py", line 66, in scrape
    text = [ data.contents[0].get_text(), data.contents[1].get_text() ] 
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bs4/element.py", line 737, in __getattr__
  AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

I tried to get above element string to **person** array.

I need the result to look like this:

```
  print person['Name']
  #output Piter
  print person['Year']
  #output 2017
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
           <span class="strong">Name</span>
           <span class="pull-right">Piter</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
           <span class="strong">Year</span>
           <span class="pull-right">2017</span>
        </li>
 </ul>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

need = {}

for li_tag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'list-group'}):
    for span_tag in li_tag.find_all('li', {'class':'list-group-item'}):
        field = span_tag.find('span', {'class':'strong'}).text
        value = span_tag.find('span', {'class':'pull-right'}).text
        need[field] = value

print(need)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
I tested according to my one, Only last one picked up.  "Year" only.
I think we show pus some another for loop after span_tag ?

Comment: I printed out span_tag.  it looks like `<li class="list-group-item"> <span class="strong">Name</span>
<span class="pull-right">Piter</span>
</li><li class="list-group-item">
           <span class="strong">Year</span>
           <span class="pull-right">2017</span>
        </li>`

Comment: I tried 
`print   field` but got nothing as out put,  but when I print `span_tag.find('span', {'class':'strong'}).text` show the output `New` and `Year`

Comment: check this, I face another issue.  https://hastebin.com/acimalamin.cs  when I try to same method.